# Error on XCode: fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': Device not configured

Tags: xcode

I'm using Version 13.0 beta 5 (13A5212g)
and while updating bot MacOs and the Beta Version my keychain got messed up.

I had to update the passwords for all the accounts including Github & the appleID
But now Xcode does not recognize my credentials.

Already tried this method with no success:

git remote add origin https://{username}:{password}@github.com/{username}/project.git